# JavaScript to load from text field, edit the contents as per need and save it to the system

Tags: javascript

I have used JavaScript to load text file from the system and display it in the text area of the form. After loading the file, I want to edit it and save it back to the system. But I am not sure how to save it back.

This is my code to load the text.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 // ui events

 function inputFilePassageToTranslate_Changed(inputFilePassageToTranslate){

     var fileToLoad = inputFilePassageToTranslate.files[0];

     var fileReader = new FileReader();

     fileReader.onload = inputFilePassageToTranslate_Changed_FileLoaded;

     fileReader.readAsText(fileToLoad);
 }


 function inputFilePassageToTranslate_Changed_FileLoaded(event){

     var passageToTranslate = event.target.result;

     var textareaPassageToTranslate = document.getElementById("textareaPassageToTranslate");

     textareaPassageToTranslate.value = passageToTranslate;

 }
</script>
```

Comment: You cannot read nor write file to/from filesystem without a server. Unless you use files in browser (like attachments) and use blobs to read it. Look into nodejs and express to setup a simple server

Answer (score 0):

You can simply load data from a text file using jquery ajax like this

```
jQuery.get('http://localhost/pathtotextfile.txt', function(data) {
    var textdata = data;
    // Put text data to a textarea as follows 
    $('#yourtextareaid').val(textdata);
});
```

You need any server side language to do a file write on server (In php we can achieve this using the code )

```
<?php
 $myFile = "ttt.txt";
 $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
 $stringData = $_POST["name"];
 fwrite($fh, $stringData);
 fclose($fh);
?>
```

Using the ajax

```
$.ajax({
  method:"post",
  action:"savefile.php",
  data:{
      name :$('#yourtextareaid').val()
  }
success:function(data){
  alert('successfully saved');
}
});
```